# Very slow debugging of native code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I put a breakpoint to my native code.
However when I attach the debugger, the app becomes inactive and it takes a while (10-15 minutes) until Android Studio stops at the breakpoint and allow me to do debugging.
Is it possible to fix this lag somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Could the loging help you?
If you write debug logs, you can check it in the logcat

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know how to log in native c code. BTW, it seems I had too much active breakpoint. When I removed all unused breakpoints then it bacame much more faster.

Comment: Nice. Good to know that :)